# ShowDialog not showing WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, showdialog

```
Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

var dialog = new Login();

dialog.ShowDialog();

var mainWindow = new MainWindow(dialog.success, DBInteraction.getPID(dialog.txtLoginUser.Text));

mainWindow.ShowDialog();

this.MainWindow = mainWindow;

if (mainWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
{

}
```

Strange thing is that the window never actually gets shown if i debug this it just jumps over those showDialog points and does not show them at all.
My login is shown perfectly fine.

As you can see i already tried various recommend in other threads regarding this topic this.MainWindow = mainWindow and setting the ShutdownMode to explicit.

Full call:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaktionslogik für "App.xaml"
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void ApplicationStart(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {

        Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
        var dialog = new Login();

        dialog.ShowDialog();

        var mainWindow = new MainWindow(dialog.success, DBInteraction.getPID(dialog.txtLoginUser.Text));

        mainWindow.ShowDialog();

        this.MainWindow = mainWindow;

        if (mainWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Boosting.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Startup="ApplicationStart"
         ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Is this a typo `MainWindow.ShowDialog();`? Because it looks like it should be `mainWindow.ShowDialog()` Where are you calling this code from?

Comment: "App.xaml.cs". Is a typo yes, will edit that.

Comment: Where in App.xaml.cs, Application_Startup(); App() constructor? TypeInitialization exceptions might be 'swallowed' away in the App constructor.

Comment: Added the full call. If i assign the mainWindown.ShowDialog() to a var its always null. If i take a look at the mainWindow Properties they are all there the ShowActivated one is even true http://bit.ly/1ETHEBr.

Comment: Verify the `Visibility`.

Comment: It might be possible that there is no thread for UI available anymore, even with the ExplicitShutdown option. Why are you using `ShowDialog()`? Can't you use mainWindow.Show() from within the success 'method' of your login dialog? That would, of course, mean that the login dialog must also be shown using the `Show()` method.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino do you mean SetVisibility, thats on true.

Comment: @Silvermind if i turn the login in dialog to show they both appear and i can onyl access the mainwindow, if i turn both to show they both show and than the application shuts down immediately.

Comment: You are ShowDialogging the MainWin twice, is that on purpose? The 2nd will bomb.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Doesnt change anything, what Silvermind suggested calling the MainWindow inside of my Login code would work i dont really know why but i could go like that and just hide login form. But i guess thats what they call bad practice.

Comment: Post the (main tag of) App.Xaml for completeness.

Comment: @HenkHolterman You mean the code of App.Xaml ? edited that

Comment: Yes, that Startup event is not commonly used.

Comment: No direct repro, I only get an exception on the 2nd mainWindow.ShowDialog(). The first one works fine. Investigate your MainWindow's constructor, OnLoad etc.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Strange, i changed that to a single call of ShowDialog doesnt work either

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do in case you didn't do it already :

1. Remove the `StartupUri` from the Application XAML file
2. Set startup handler in app XAML  :
3. Add the `Show()` to MainWindow after the dialog show :

   ```
   private void ApplicationStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   {
      Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
      var dialog = new Login();
      dialog.ShowDialog();
      var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
      mainWindow.ShowDialog();
   }
   ```
4. One last step. WPF set the first created window as the MainWindow in an app. Show inside your Login.xaml.cs set the MainWindow to null so that the next windows created takes precedence.

   ```
       if (App.Current.MainWindow == this)
       {
           App.Current.MainWindow = null;
       }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Olaru for making the edits. For some reason code formatting stopped working for me.